# Angular svg as template for component shown as text

Tags: javascript, html, angular, svg

I'm currently trying to display a svg icon by using Angular component like this

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-profile-icon',
    templateUrl: './profile-icon.svg',
    styleUrls: ['./profile-icon.component.scss'],
})
export class ProfleIconComponent {
}
```

An I call this element in a html file. This component is instantiated but with no svg content. Just the path of the svg with some random text.

[image]

Is some Angular configuration I missed? Because it works fine if I wrote like this without the component, or just copy paste the svg content to a html template.

```
<img src='./profile-icon.svg'>
```

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Add assets folder to your angular.json.

```
"assets": [
    "src/assets"
 ],
```

Then access the SVG icon in the HTML template like below -

```
<img src="/assets/profile-icon.svg">
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old, but if somebody else falls here, I've got the same problem trying to show a big SVG file, just got the name of the SVG file in text.

Not sure, but probably because I'm using an old version (Angular 6).

Solved by renaming the `svg` file as `html` and changing the `templateUrl`to point the renamed html file.